# Change page content with javascript isn't working on returning to the homepage again

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xmlhttprequest

My website consists of 6 html files , 1 is the index page which contain the homepage content and there is a file called homepage that I use to load the homepage content again , The navigation menu contain 5 `<li>` elements that I use to navigate to the pages .

```
<div class="navigators">
   <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#" data-f="homepage">Home</a></li>
      <li id="tab1"><a href="#" data-f="organizations">Organizations</a></li>
      <li id="tab2"><a href="#" data-f="takeaction">Take Action</a></li>
      <li id="tab3"><a href="#" data-f="resources">Resources</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-f="contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

On the homepage I have some sections that change the website content to a page from (organizations - take action - resources).

```
<div class="group">
    <a data-id="tab1" data-file="organizations" href="#">
        <img src="images/1-group2.png">
        <h2>Organizations</h2>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="action">
    <a data-id="tab2" data-file="takeaction" href="#">
        <img src="images/1-action.png">
        <h2>Take Action</h2>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="resources">
    <a data-id="tab3" data-file="resources" href="#">
       <h2>Resources</h2>
    </a>    
</div>
```

When I click on one of them for the first time it works successfully and load change the index.html content , But when I click on "Home" from the navigation menu and click on one of these it's not working.

Here is the Javascript code :

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.content a' ), function(ele) {
        ele.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

            var file = ele.getAttribute('data-file')+'.html';
            var include = document.getElementById('content');

        // Add/Remove 'active' class to/from <li> in the navigation menu
        document.querySelector(".tabs li.active").classList.remove("active");
        var selected = ele.getAttribute('data-id');
        document.getElementById(selected).classList.add("active");

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {   // XMLHttpRequest.DONE == 4
               if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                   include.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

               }
               else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
                  alert('There was an error 400');
               }
               else {
                   alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
               }
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open("GET", file, true);
        xmlhttp.send();



        });

    });
```

Here is the website :
http://jhtml.aba.ae

To get what I mean click on one of the `<h2>` elements at the end of the page (Organizations - Resources - Take Action) , It would load the clicked one content , then click homepage from the navigation menu and try to click on one of the `<h2>` elements again and see what happen , No thing happen like there is no js code , It doesn't even show an error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the click event listeners.

You have one set of listeners that changes the `active` class

```
// Add/Remove 'active' class to/from <li> in the navigation menu
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.tabs li'), function(el) {
        el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            document.querySelector(".tabs li.active").classList.remove("active");
            el.classList.add("active");
        });
    });
```

the other changes is on the `a` tags that changes the innerHtml.

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.tabs li a'), function(ele) {
        ele.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

            var file = ele.getAttribute('data-f')+'.html';
            var include = document.getElementById('content');

            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {   // XMLHttpRequest.DONE == 4
                   if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                       include.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

                   }
                   else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
                      alert('There was an error 400');
                   }
                   else {
                       alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
                   }
                }
            };

            xmlhttp.open("GET", file, true);
            xmlhttp.send();


        });
    });
```

since the `.tabs li` elements contains the `a` tags, the user can click on the tab, without touching the link, making a style change without changing the innerHtml.

wrapping those changes into the a single event listener should fix it.

Comment: I'm not talking about the navigators on the header , I'm talking about the `<a>` containing the `<h2>` elements on the homepage

Comment: @guyyoget , when I click on one of the `<a>` containing the `<h2>` elements it should remove/add active class and load its content

Comment: This happens on clicking it from the index.html , but when I click on homepage on the navigation menu and click one of the `<h2>` elements nothing of this happen

Comment: oh... ok, so I found a different bug :) .